# Cubic Function with two roots and its Derivative function with one root

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I am working on polynomial function, when it is possible for a polynomial function to have less real distinct root than its derivative function. I am curious whether any form or example of a cubic function with real coefficient that have only two real distinct roots, and its derivative function has only one real distinct root. Could you please give me an example of this condition? It would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to *real* roots of cubics with *real* coefficients?

Comment: yes, that's what I ment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between any two (distinct) real roots of a cubic with real coefficients, its derivative has a real root, by Rolle's Theorem.  Now the only way a cubic with real coefficients can have just two (distinct) real roots is if one of them is a *double* root.  But if a cubic has a double root, that root is also a root of the derivative.  Thus the derivative will have two distinct real roots.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That's quite good

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- a cubic polynomial with *real* coefficients can have either $1$ or $3$ real roots, never $2$;
- the derivative of a cubic is a quadratic, which can have either $2$ or $0$ real roots, never $1$;
- look at cubics which have both a local maximum and a local minimum, but no real root in between them, such as for example $x^3-x+1$.

Comment: (x-1)(x+1)^2 is a cubic function but has only two real roots. and for the second point, is there any theory or link that I can look further? Thanks.

Comment: @YoklyLeng $-1$ is a double root, so to avoid ambiguities it is commonly said that $(x-1)(x+1)^2$ has $3$ roots counting multiplicities, but $2$ *distinct* roots. As for the second point, the derivative can have either less or more distinct real roots than the polynomial itself, and I am not sure what other theory you are looking for.

Comment: Oh now i got you answer and I edited my question. So, for your second point, I am wondering whether there is any link that I can use for citation if I quote it.

Comment: @YoklyLeng For the edited question, look at the answer posted by Barry Chipra.

Comment: Yep, thank you so much. Now, I know what to do now. Thanks.